# Copy files with date/time range in filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, cp

I have a bash script, which contains the following lines:

```
for ((iTime=starttime;iTime<=endtime;iTime++))
do
    find . -name "*${iTime}*" -exec cp --parents \{\} ${dst} \;
done
```

I have a structure with a few folders including subfolders and many files at the bottom of the tree. These files are labeled with date and time info in the filename, like "filename_2021063015300000_suffix". The time is in format yyyymmddhhmmss and two digits for 1/10 and 1/100 seconds. I have a lot of files, which means, that my approach is very slow. The files have a time distance of a few minutes, so only a couple of files (e.g. 10 per subfolder out of >10000) should be copied.

How can i find all the files in the time range and get them all in one find and copy command? Maybe get a list of all the files to copy with one find command and then copy the list of filepathes? But how can i do this?

Comment: Do the filename and suffix change depending on the file, or is that a literal "filename" and "suffix"? Also, do you know ahead of time whether the filename and suffix contain numbers or underscores?

Comment: I think I'd pipe the `find` output into `awk`, along with start and end time as variables, and filter them there - it will be very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your time span is reasonably limited, just inline the acceptable file names into the single `find` command.

```sh
find . \( -false $(for ((iTime=starttime;iTime<=endtime;iTime++)); do printf ' %s' -o -name "*$iTime*"; done) \) -exec cp --parents \{\} ${dst} \;
```

The initial `-false` predicate inside the parentheses is just to simplify the following predicates so that they can all start with `-o -name`.

This could end up with an "argument list too long" error if your list of times is long, though.  Perhaps a more robust solution is to pass the time resolution into the command.

```sh
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
  for f; do
    for ((iTime=starttime;iTime<=endtime;iTime++)); do
      if [[ $f == *"$iTime"* ]]; then
        cp --parents "$f" "$0"
        break
      fi
    done' "$dst" {} +
```

The script inside `-exec` could probably be more elegant; if your file names have reasonably regular format, maybe just extract the timestamp and compare it numerically to check whether it's in range.  Perhaps also notice how we abuse the `$0` parameter after `bash -c '...'` to pass in the value of `$dst`.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `find`. I created -

```
filename_2020063015300000_suffix 
filename_2021053015300000_suffix 
filename_2021063015300000_suffix 
filename_2022063015300000_suffix
foo/filename_2021053015312345_suffix
bar/baz/filename_2021053015310101_suffix
```

So if I execute

```
starttime=2021000000000000
endtime=2022000000000000
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*; do       # for all these
  ts=${f//[^0-9]/}                      # trim to date
  (( ts >= starttime )) || continue     # skip too old
  (( ts <= endtime   )) || continue     # skip too new
  echo "$f"                             # list matches
done | xargs -I{} echo cp {} /new/dir/  # pass to xargs
```

I get

```
cp bar/baz/filename_2021053015310101_suffix /new/dir/
cp filename_2021053015300000_suffix /new/dir/
cp filename_2021063015300000_suffix /new/dir/
cp foo/filename_2021053015312345_suffix /new/dir/
```

There *are* ways to simplify that glob. If you use `extglob` you can make it shorter, and check more carefully with a regex - for example,

```
shopt -s globstar extglob
for f in **/*_+([0-9])_*; do
  [[ "$f" =~ _[0-9]{16}_ ]] || continue;
```

It starts looking complicated and hard to maintain for the next guy, though.

Comment: I believe the find is being used in the original question because the files in question may be distributed across multiple directories.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, so i go for tripleees answer.

Comment: Always go for what works, but can you tell me how it fails? I'd like to correct so it maybe works for someone else.

Comment: Unfortunately had no time till now, the answer from tripleee was the only one which was working out of the box and which i was understanding.

problem in your answer: ts={$f//[^0-9]/} displays all digits in the filename, so if there are other digits in the filename than the date/time digits, it won't work. How can i adapt this line, that only the 16 digits between the two underscores are assigned to ts?

Comment: `[[ "$f" =~ _[0-9]{16}_ ]]` (with extended globbing as mentioned) matches exactly and only filenames with 16 digits between underscores. If you don't want extended globbing and the separate match to check you could use for `f in **/*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*`.

Answer (score -1):

Try these, replace the `dst`, `starttime`, `endtime` in your case, both work for me on `Ubuntu16.04`.

```
find . -type f -regextype sed -regex "[^_]*_[0-9]\{16\}_[^_]*" -exec bash -c 'dt=$(echo "$0" | grep -oP "\d{16}"); [ "$dt" -gt "$2" ] && [ "$dt" -lt "$3" ] && cp -p "$0" "$1"' {} 'dst/' 'starttime' 'endtime' \;
```

*$0 is filename which contain the datetime, $1 is dst directory path, $2 is starttime, $3 is endtime*

Or

```
find . -type f -regextype sed -regex "[^_]*_[0-9]\{16\}_[^_]*" | awk -v dst='/tmp/test_find/' '{if (0 == system("[ $(echo \"" $0 "\"" " | grep -oP \"" "(?<=_)\\d+(?=_)\") -gt starttime ] && [ $(echo \"" $0 "\"" " | grep -oP \"" "(?<=_)\\d+(?=_)\") -lt endtime ]")) {system("cp -p " $0 " " dst)}}'
```

Both of them, first, use `find` to find the file name which has the pattern like `_2021063015300000_` (maybe this has 16 digital but you say this pattern `format yyyymmddhhmmss` only has 14 digital) with `sed regex`.

Then use `-exec bash -c "get datetime in filename, compare them with times, and exec cp action"`

Or use `awk` to get the datetime and compare with start or end time by `system` command, and will execute `cp` to `dst` directory at last also by `system` command.

PS. this pattern are dependent the filename which only has the `datetime` between two `_`.

Comment: I do not vote your answer down, anyway unfortunately it is not working for me, so i will go with tripleees answer

Comment: OK, could you get me some error tips while it's not working for you ?